# X not running after pkg upgrade

Tags: freebsd

After doing a `pkg upgrade` today to my FreeBSD 12.0, X stopped starting.

When I do

`start-lumina-desktop`

I receive back the output:

```
No X11 session detected: Lumina will try to start one...
/usr/local/bin/X: Undefined symbol "alphasort"
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

I am using X with the `scfb` driver in a Lenovo Ideapad 100S IBR 14'', and it was working properly before the security upgrade.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it might be related to the ABI change in FreeBSD 12-CURRENT.  Differently from stable branches, the CURRENT is not guaranteed to keep a stable ABI.  This means the packages might get built for a newer ABI than that of your system.

Note the in this (ino64 case) the upgrade needs to be done in a specific way: the usual method of "make buildworld buildkernel installkernel installworld" will render your system unusable.  Follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/UPDATING) (the "20170523" entry).

When that's done, use pkg(8) as usual.